# Bootstrap modal popup not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a simple modal popup using Bootstrap. I got the sample from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals, my code looks like this..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i run in on my browser and click the button, the popup shows only in miliseconds and then closing again..how to prevent the popup from closing like that?

Comment: Looks like it's answered, but as a side note, you should load scripts before the closing `body` tag. When they're in the `head` like that they slow page rendering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> // This JS have all necessary files
```

Remove below JS from your file

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hEUAz/)

Comment: @SridharR  I added my code below and I can't get it to work can you please take a look, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Take care of all the (old) examples and tutorials, you find across the web and bootstrap 5.

The code for bootstrap5 looks slightly different, e.g.
`data-toggle` hast turned to `data-bs-toggle`.
so a complete BS5-example looks more [like](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/):

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...I tested popup stay..

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://teamtreehouse.com/assets/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://teamtreehouse.com/assets/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/global.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me! The example on bootstrap just does not work!

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of js conflict as the code for running modal is already present in bootstrap.js and you were also using bootstrap-modal.js

For future reference if you include bootstrap.js in you code then you don't have to include any additional js file to run any components of bootstrap. ( except of jQuery file obviously :D )